# Why is it when I set "closeOnEscape" to false and then "closeOnEscape" to true jquery dialog escape does not work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui 1.8 and I have a model dialog that popups up and if a user clicks on a checkbox another one comes up.

This requires them to say "yes" or "no" so I removed the "X" on the dialog and put closeOnEscape to false.

However I noticed when I did that the model dialog underneath it would close when they hit escape. So now when the one that pops up when the checkbox is checked I disable closeOnEscape on the first dialog box.

When they close it I enable again yet it does not work. I am not sure why

```
$("#Dialog").dialog( "option", "closeOnEscape", true);
```

I even do this in firebug. I just open my first dialog up

Do this in firebugs console

```
$("#Dialog").dialog( "option", "closeOnEscape", false);
```

Then verify that escape is now disabled. I then try to enable it again

```
$("#Dialog").dialog( "option", "closeOnEscape", true);
```

Yet it never enables.

**Edit**

Ok I figured it out it does work.... The thing is the user has to click on footer part of the dialog(where the buttons sit). This of course is not ideal since who is going to think of clicking on that area to get that to work?

Comment: Rather than fiddling with the escapes of the dialog beneath it, why not just close the dialog underneath it and re-open it when the one on top closes using the close event?

Comment: Then I have to keep track of any changes they made to any of the fields in the dialog I am reopening and closing. Plus the form in the dialog box of that one is generated through ajax it would need to do another ajax request on top of it.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Didn't know it was generated via an AJAX call. In that case, how about hiding/showing the underlying dialog instead of closing/opening it?

Comment: Hmm I could try that. I am not sure if the dialog ignores the close command if hidden.

Comment: It might not ignore the close command if it is hidden - but you could use the `beforeclose` event and check if the dialog is visible, and if not return false and prevent it from closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the focus back to the checkbox in the first dialog (or some tabbable element inside the dialog container).

Let's say the dialog that is opened when you click the checkbox -- the one with Yes/No -- has the id `yesNoDialog`. And let's say the checkbox in the first dialog (`#Dialog`, i guess) has the id `theCheckbox`. Then when you close `yesNoDialog`, you regain focus back to `theCheckbox`. Like this

```
$("#yesNoDialog").dialog({
    close: function() {
        $("#theCheckbox").focus();
    }
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JAU7p/)