# Stop fancybox closing when user presses Esc

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using fancybox on a page, but I'm using it as more of a design feature than a jQuery modal. I am trying to stop the user from being able to close it (as it will "break" the design of the page). I have managed to stop the user from clicking off fancybox, but I am having trouble stopping it close when the Esc key is pressed. I have tried `'closeOnEscape': false` but this doesn't seem to work. Below is my code. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong or what I need to do?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fancybox({
        'width': '340px',
        'height': '100%',
        'autoScale': true,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type': 'iframe',
        'href': 'form.php',
        'hideOnContentClick': false,
        'closeBtn' : false,
        'helpers' : { 
            'overlay' : {
                'closeClick': false,
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what version of fancybox are you using?

Comment: This will not help you but if you're using it as a design feature it's probably easier just to build something similar (visually)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000884/why-is-it-when-i-set-closeonescape-to-false-and-then-closeonescape-to-true-j

Comment: The API option `modal`: If set to `true`, will disable navigation and closing.

Answer (score 16):

Check the `keys` option from [fancyBox docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs):

> **keys**
>   Define keyboard keys for gallery navigation, closing and slideshow
>   Object; Default value:

```
{
    next : {
        13 : 'left', // enter
        34 : 'up',   // page down
        39 : 'left', // right arrow
        40 : 'up'    // down arrow
    },
    prev : {
        8  : 'right',  // backspace
        33 : 'down',   // page up
        37 : 'right',  // left arrow
        38 : 'down'    // up arrow
    },
    close  : [27], // escape key
    play   : [32], // space - start/stop slideshow
    toggle : [70]  // letter "f" - toggle fullscreen
}
```

Just map the `close` value to `null`.

---

If you are using fancyBox2, add this property to your code:

```
$.fancybox({
  // all your other options here
  ...,
  keys : {
    close  : null
  }
}
```

Comment: are you able to incorporate the code I need in my existing code? I don't really have any experience with javascript or fancyBox

Comment: Oddly, this answer didn't work for me. I found that `modal: true,` seemed to work

Comment: Setting the close key to null causes an error when closing fancybox in the thumbnail mode. Rather set it to 0 to avoid the error.

Answer (score 2):

@moonwave99 has the correct answer for fancybox2.
If you are using v1.3+ then you must use:

```
enableEscapeButton: false
```

Ref: http://fancybox.net/api

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in comments, `modal: true` works perfectly...

```
$.fancybox({
    modal: true
});
```

From [the docs...](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

> **modal** - If set to true, will disable navigation and closing.